# Read a file from specific path Xamarin.Forms

Tags: file, xamarin.forms, io

I have the following path on Android device:

`storage/sdcard0/Android/data/.../files/`

How can I read file from the specific path in Xamarin.Forms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the normal System.IO classes, like

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```